# How make something like Facebook Notifications?

Tags: javascript, css, notifications

**Please, read all the question before thinking wrong things.**

[image: Implementing a Facebook Notifications like style]

I'm trying to implement a Facebook Notifications system like, but I need some help for style this. I already make the notifications, the back-end works perfectly, but I'm using a workaround for style - and truste me, this is slow, ugly and can't provide to me a good way to style the source.

What I'm exatcly talking about is the actions that occurs between "user click in Notifications" and "user receive loaded Notifications". I'm talking about the style of this part. Things like "how I can open a box with loaded notifications?" after click in a button/div/image/text.

Okay, let's continue with that. 
Now I'm using [Fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox) to create my notifications box - yes, FANCYBOX! Following is the visual that I get with Fancybox after click in "notifications" button (the "0"):

[image: My Notification with Fancybox]

This may appears beautiful for you, but for me it's ugly - and this is really, really slow. 
For make this workaround, I disabled the images of Fancybox, so when it loads, it loads without the black background, the "X" to close the window and other things. Following is my code.

### Partially responsable for header:

```
<!-- This is the html generated by Ruby on Rails,number is dynamic-->
<a href="/notifications/index" class="various fancybox.ajax">0</a>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".various").fancybox({
      openEffect: 'none',
      closeEffect: 'none',
      prevEffect: 'none',
      nextEffect: 'none',
      fitToView : false,
      autoSize: false,
      scrolling: 'auto',
      maxWidth:300,
      maxHeight:500,
      padding: 0,
      leftRatio: 0.86,
      topRatio: 0.18
    });
  });
</script>
```

### This is generated HTML of notifications/index/ (for pratical example):

```
<div class="post group">
        <div class="notifications-content">
        <div class="group" id="notification-0">
        <div class="post-middle">
          <div class="notifications-title">
            <b>Bruno postou:</b>
          </div>
          <div class="post-middle-text">
               ADO
          </div>
          <div class="post-middle-actions with-dots">
            <label> Postado às 12:34 de 17 de October</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="notifications-content">
        <div class="group" id="notification-1">
        <div class="post-middle">
          <div class="notifications-title">
            <b>Fernando Paladini postou:</b>
          </div>
          <div class="post-middle-text">
              hummmmmmmmm #boilo
          </div>
          <div class="post-middle-actions with-dots">
            <label> Postado às 12:36 de 17 de October</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="notifications-content">
        <div class="group" id="notification-2">
        <div class="post-middle">
          <div class="notifications-title">
            <b><a href="#">@Ramon Diogo</a> postou:</b>
          </div>
          <div class="post-middle-text">
              http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A3zPI-DBf7U
          </div>
          <div class="post-middle-actions with-dots">
              <label></label>
              <label>Comentado às 12:47 de 17 de October</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

How I can do that with just HTML, CSS and jQuery / JS? I mean, this effects of when click on button open a "box" with the loaded contents, and when click out closes the "box". I really, really have no idea how to make this. Actually I'm using Fancybox opening a modal, but I don't want open a model, I want make this like Facebook and sites like Trello do - just css/jquery.

**Note** that I'm not asking for code, I need help because I don't have any ideia how to do this. I want the instructions: what I need make to when click the button, open the notifications box. Or when click outside notification box, close the notification box. The concepts behind this, but I will consider if you post some code too, because will help me with the learning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that with absolute positioning on the div that contains your notifications.

It should be hidden as a default behavior and you make it visible on click with javascript.

This will help you: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-create-a-drop-down-nav-menu-with-html5-css3-and-jquery/ but you should change the behavior to react to the click event instead of mouseenter (line 14 of the script part). Replace that part with something like:

```
$(this).click(function(e) {  
    $(this).find("ul").stop(true, true).slideDown();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

notice the "preventDefault part? that is to avoid the browser to enter the link when you click.

Comment: This don't helped me at all, but thanks for your reply. I will thumb up you, but I can't give you best answer, but this trully don't helped me a lot.